# How to send a file to the Heroku home directory

Tags: heroku, vaadin

I am mainly trying to deploy vaadin chart app to Heroku. Vaadin chart needs a license file. During compile time it looks for the license file at user's home directory. I can build and run the app locally. But when I deploy the app to Heroku, it fails as:-

> [ERROR] License for Vaadin Charts 4 not found. Go to vaadin.com/pro
>   for more details.

So surely I have to send the license file to Heroku home directory. How can I send it?

Comment: How are you running your app? As far as I remember and [the doc states](https://vaadin.com/license), "_There is no license needed for deploying the results or by end users. Furthermore, there are little limitations for distributing (or selling) the results._"

Comment: I am trying to run a Vaadin chart app. Definalty it needs a paid or a developer license to run. I can run it locally. But the deployment to Heroku fails. Because there is no Vaadin chart license in Heroku home directory. I have to send the license to Heroku home directory. That is what I don't know.

Comment: Ok, but could you please explain how exactly are you running your app, and when exactly are you getting the error message?

Comment: I build and run from IntelliJ IDE. But at the beginning, I was missing the local license file. When I place Vaadin chart license in my home directory, it worked perfectly.  In Heroku CLI when I enter git push heroku master. Heroku starts to build the app automatically by using maven. During the build obviously, it looks for the license file at heroku home directory. Since it is missing I got the error "[ERROR] License for Vaadin Charts 4 not found. Go to vaadin.com/pro for more details"